# Images delay in slide show before they display

Tags: javascript

So im trying to use my images as a background, and I want them to be on a loop so it changes between the three, below is my code the looping seems to be working but I have two issues I can't seem to resolve:

- the timer starts before the slides do (the screen is black for 7
  seconds and then the first image shows, im assuming the timer is in
  the wrong section of the code but I moved it around a few times and
  it does the same thing. how do I get it to load the site with the
  first image?
- the images show up very small and don't fill out the screen like I want it to (automatically) ive tried several codes that should automatically figure out screen size and fill it accordingly, but they dont seem to work...any suggestions?

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Kess Agency" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us">
    <meta http-equiv="created by kess" content="en-us">
    <style>
    body{
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-position: 300 200;

    }
    </style>
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//auto resize



    var imgs=new Array()
    imgs[0]="images/img1.png";
    imgs[1]="images/img2.png";
    imgs[2]="images/img3.png";
    //time between slides
    var speed=7000
    //preload images
    var processed=new Array()
    for(i=0;i<imgs.length;i++){
        processed[i]=new Image();
        processed[i].src=imgs[i];
    }
    var inc=-1;
    function slideimg(){
        if (inc<imgs.length-1)
            inc++;
        else
            inc=0;
        document.body.background=processed[inc].src;
    }
    if (document.all || document.getElementById)
    window.onload=new Function('setInterval("slideimg()",speed)');

</script>

</head>
 <body>
     <p class= "type"></p>
</body>
</html>​
```

Comment: Setting up an example in http://jsfiddle.net or http://tinkerbin.com would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are waiting until the page loads and then running setInterval. As far as I know setInterval will wait until the interval is done and will then run. One way you could do it is..

```
function slideimg(){
    if (inc<imgs.length-1)
        inc++;
    else
        inc=0;
    document.body.background=processed[inc].src;
    setTimeout(function(){
        slideimg();
    }, speed);
}

window.onload = function () {
    slideimg();
};
```

This way the script will run onload and the once loaded it will wait and then run again. Another benefit of doing things this way rather than using setInterval is that this way the process will finish before running again (setInterval will just try to run the script every 'whatever' seconds you chose, whether things have loaded or not.

For the background sizing you could try setting the css to `background-size: cover;` although this is new (CSS3).

Comment: oh ok cool, thanks. Now i just get a syntax error saying slideImg() is not defined, sorry im kind of a noob would you mind helping me out with that?

Comment: I made a mistake in my capitalisation so it was looking for a function that didn't exist. Changed now. For reference `slideImg` was changed to `slideimg` in the onload function.

Comment: ah, duh i could have caught that lol, thank you for your help.